# How do I render a verbatim/code/pre plus sign with RDoc markup?

Tags: ruby, markup, rdoc

Using RDoc markup and generating docs with Yard, I'm trying to document some command output that has a line like:

```
+----------------------------------+
```

...but can't figure out how to achieve this.  How can I end up with HTML:

```
<pre class="code">
  +----------------------------------+
</pre>
```

I'm sure I missed something trivial in the docs...

---

**Try #1**

Without trying to escape the markup, I indent this 2 spaces (like any other code/pre block):

```
+----------------------------------+
```

...generate the docs, and get HTML (as expected, I suppose):

```
<pre class="code">
  <tt>----------------------------------</tt>
</pre>
```

---

**Try #2**

If I use a backslash to escape, this markup:

```
\+----------------------------------+
```

...becomes this HTML:

```
<pre class="code">
  \+----------------------------------+
</pre>
```

---

**Try #3**

Oddly enough, if I use two plus signs in succession, this markup:

```
++----------------------------------+
```

...becomes this HTML:

```
<pre class="code">
  ++----------------------------------+
</pre>
```

---

**Try #4**

Using unindented `<tt>` just leaves me with a non-"verbatim" (i.e. pre/code) section; just plain-text (again, as expected, I suppose):

```
<tt>+----------------------------------+</tt>
```

...becomes this HTML:

```
<p>
  <tt>-------------------------------------</tt>
</p>
```

---

**Try #5**

Using indented `<tt>` turns this markup:

```
<tt>+----------------------------------+</tt>
```

...into this HTML:

```
<pre class="code">
  <tt>+----------------------------------+</tt>
</pre>
```

Comment: Looks like a potential problem with Yard.  This renders just fine when generating via rdoc 3.10.

Comment: Logged bug with Yard: https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and fixed in yard: https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/403.